# Intagrate China MS Azure Cognitive Services with the Global one for WEB

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-china

I am using Global MS Azure cognitive services SDK in WEB application (JavaScript) using websocket connection Speech-to-Text. How can I use Speech-to-Text with credentials for MS Azure China? It has different region at least and different link for websocket? 
Does exist another SDK for China?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to some impacts of policy in China, Azure China and Azure Global are two independent systems. If you want to use Azure Speech-to-Text service in China, you should have an Azure China subscription and create a speech-service.

It does have different regions and endpoints in speech-service. If you are using JS SDK to do your development work, there are two things of Azure China Speech service that you need to know :

1. There is only one region in China that you can create speech-service: `chinaeast2`
2. Its endpoint is different from Azure global, as there is only one region that you can create/use Speech service, so there is only one endpoint here which is: `chinaeast2.stt.speech.azure.cn`

If you are using JS SDK to call Azure Speech-to-Text services, you can still use this SDK here but you should change the endpoint in sdk source code, for instance, in `microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js` you should go to line 6293 to change its host from Azure Global to Azure China:
[image]

I also did some test on my side for you ,this is my speech service in Azure China :
[image]

Official samle html gets [from here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/index.html) .

Test result :
[image]

It works me perfectly on speech to text service.

Hope it helps !